# Chaining Extensions in XML Schemas

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

It is possible have a "chain" of extensions in an XML schema? That is, can one define a data type C that extends B that extends A? I have a schema that looks like this:

```
   <complexType name="ServiceRequest">
      <sequence>
         <element name="validate" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" default="false" />
      </sequence>
   </complexType>

   <complexType name="DataModificationRequest">
      <complexContent>
         <extension base="efms:ServiceRequest">
            <sequence>
               <element name="user-id" type="efms:UserID" />
            </sequence>
         </extension>
      </complexContent>
   </complexType>

    <complexType name="CreateTrackRequest">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="efms:DataModificationRequest"> 
                <sequence>
                    <element name="segment-number" type="efms:SegmentNumber" />
                    <element name="segment-subnumber" type="efms:SegmentSubnumber" />
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
```

When I look at these items in the Design View of Oxygen XML, the **DataModificationRequest** correctly shows the **validate** element from **ServiceRequest**. But **CreateTrackRequest** does not show any of the elements I expected it to inherit from its parent (**DataModificationRequest**) and grandparent (**ServiceRequest**).

OxygenXML says the schema validates correctly, but the grandchild isn't inheriting elements as I intended. Am I doing something wrong, or am I not allowed to have an chain of extensions like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the mystery. I had simplified my original post for purposes of the forum. But in reality, the third data type (**CreateTrackRequest**) was in a separate schema file. Despite the fact that we're using version 14.0 of the Oxygen XML editor, Oxygen is apparently not smart enough to show parent/grandparent elements in design view, if the parent/grandparent is in a different file.

I was able to prove this by having Oxygen generate a sample XML instance document, with all the optional fields. The instance correctly included the elements from the parent & grandparent data types.

(Clenches fists & slinks away...)